# Compare the first field of each line whose first field is "2000" till a different field is found

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

My goal is to compare the first field of each line whose first field is "2000" till I find a different field.

Let say the different field is located in line number 6, as in the provided example; in that case I'd ask Bash to print line number 5, which is the line before the line "No Living Leaves":

```
  2000 255    17.    11.     0.    30.  0.05  97. 0.110  6.7  6.7  596. 0.03 0.27  0  0
  2000 256    17.    11.     0.    30.  0.05  97. 0.109  6.7  6.7  596. 0.03 0.22  0  0
  2000 257    17.    11.     0.    30.  0.05  97. 0.109  6.7  6.7  596. 0.02 0.20  0  0
  2000 258    17.    11.     0.    30.  0.05  97. 0.109  6.7  6.7  596. 0.02 0.16  0  0
  2000 259    17.    11.     0.    30.  0.05  97. 0.109  6.6  6.6  596. 0.02 0.18  0  0
  No Living leaves
```

Comment: So you said you want to compare first fields of the file . . .How many fields ? First 3 ? In your example it's up to 13th field the data is the same

Comment: Now you lost me, could you simply tell what the script should to froma a to b?

Comment: So is this just about printing line 6? Or is this about printing the first line whose first field is not `2000`?

Comment: @Serg: each line contains 16 numbers. all lines starts with "2000". I want to compare this "2000" in each line till I find odd value (text or another number). In my case, I compare the "2000" till I reach a text which is "No Living Leaves"

Comment: @kos : each line contains 16 numbers. all lines starts with "2000". I want to compare this "2000" in each line till I find odd value (text or another number). In my case, I compare the "2000" till I reach a text which is "No Living Leaves"

Comment: Ok, see mine and Serg's updated answers, both methods should avail for what you're after.

Comment: awk command is not working and I am trying the other command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments bellow kos's answer it is apparent that you want to print last line before one that differs. `AWK` approach would be the following.

```
$ awk ' $1==2000{line=$0} $1!=2000{exit}END{print line} ' OmarAli.txt                                                            
  2000 259    17.    11.     0.    30.  0.05  97. 0.109  6.6  6.6  596. 0.02 0.18  0  0
```

`bash` way would be like so:

```
$ while read LINE; do if [ "${LINE:0:4}" != "2000"  ];then print $PREV; break; fi; PREV=$LINE; done  < OmarAli.txt               
2000 259 17. 11. 0. 30. 0.05 97. 0.109 6.6 6.6 596. 0.02 0.18 0 0
```

Comment: @ Serg : the lines are in a txt file. I am still new and I wonder how to put the file name in the command. Moreover, the number of lines are changing from file to another and i need to read all the files with a loop as well

Comment: @OmarAli ok,  the way you have it in the example in your question is right - you can feed in the file to while loop at the end. But what exactly do you need to do with those lines ? What kind of processing ? I understand you want to put them into variables, but for what purpose ? Also, can you provide example ? All of these things would be nice to add to your question ( there's edit button ). And example of the text that you have would be nice,too, so we can work with actual data

Comment: your method works and I could print the file lines. My question is edited and an example is added

Comment: See my edit please, let me know if this helps

Comment: See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/718033/looping-over-lines-of-text-files-in-bash/718043?noredirect=1#comment1060413_718043)

Comment: @Serg: the provided command prints the line contains text and it is the number. However, I need to print the line before this text (the last line containing 2000)

Comment: @OmarAli I am confused. The line before `No Living Leaves` , isn't it what you wanted ?

Comment: @Serg :I do not need No Living Leaves to be printed. I need the last line containing "2000" which located above the No Living Leaves

Comment: Yes, I've edited my my `AWK` and `bash`  to do that.  Try again `awk ' $1==2000{line=$0} $1!=2000{exit}END{print line} ' inputFile.txt`

Comment: @Serg : it works and it gave me an into to go through awk http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/awk-introduction-tutorial-7-awk-print-examples/

Comment: @Serg : My last question: How about getting only one filed of that line. the edited awk command gives the whole line. I want to print the 3 field of this line

Comment: @OmarAli  If you mean print `2000 259 17` then change `line=$1" "$2" "$3` . If you mean only `17` then change `line=$3`.

Comment: @Serg : it works very well

Answer (score 2):

Using Perl:

```
perl -lane 'if($F[0]!=2000){print $x;exit}else{$x=$_}' in
```

To store the result into a variable:

```bsh
var=$(perl -lane 'if($F[0]!=2000){print $x;exit}else{$x=$_}' in)
```

- `if($F[0]!=2000){print $x;exit}`: if the first field is not `2000` prints the content of `$x` and exits;
- `else{$x=$_}`: if the first field is `2000` assigns the current record to `$x`.

This will print nothing if the first record's first field is not `2000` and the last record whose first field is `2000` otherwise.

```
% cat in
2000 255    17.    11.     0.    30.  0.05  97. 0.110  6.7  6.7  596. 0.03 0.27  0  0
2000 256    17.    11.     0.    30.  0.05  97. 0.109  6.7  6.7  596. 0.03 0.22  0  0
2000 257    17.    11.     0.    30.  0.05  97. 0.109  6.7  6.7  596. 0.02 0.20  0  0
2000 258    17.    11.     0.    30.  0.05  97. 0.109  6.7  6.7  596. 0.02 0.16  0  0
2000 259    17.    11.     0.    30.  0.05  97. 0.109  6.6  6.6  596. 0.02 0.18  0  0
No Living leaves
% perl -lane 'if($F[0]!=2000){print $x;exit}else{$x=$_}' in
2000 259    17.    11.     0.    30.  0.05  97. 0.109  6.6  6.6  596. 0.02 0.18  0  0
% var=$(perl -lane 'if($F[0]!=2000){print $x;exit}else{$x=$_}' in)
% echo $var
2000 259    17.    11.     0.    30.  0.05  97. 0.109  6.6  6.6  596. 0.02 0.18  0  0
```

Comment: See edits on the question . . .Apparently it's actually awk-able question, rather than bash-able :)

Comment: I am trying to apply the code you provided. However, I need to save the last line containing "2000" not the line containing "No Living Leaves"

Comment: @OmarAli See the updated answer.